# Make a sql select with a list in flask

Tags: python, sql, flask

I'm working in a code with flask and sql. I'm doing a json request to the datab base but i just need somecolumns so i have their names in a list and i have to pass them as params.

```
@app.route('/ajax-request', methods = ['POST'])
def ajax_request():

    table = request.form['table']

    columns = request.form.getlist('columns[]') 

    Model = ''

    if table == 'Customer':
        Model = Customer
    elif table == 'Tile':
        Model = Tile
    elif table == 'Kind_of_tile':
        Model = Kind_of_tile
    elif table == 'Tile_example':
        Model = Tile_example

    columns_query = []

    for x in columns:       
        columns_query.append(getattr(Model, x))

    columns_query = tuple(columns_query)

    for x in columns_query:
        print(x)

    query = ***Model.query.add_columns(', '.join(map(str, columns_query))).first()***

    exit();
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Note that `exit()` will kill the interpreter, ending your flask server

Comment: I putted that exit() just to make debug. But it doesn't belong there.

Comment: My question is if this code is good to use cause when I started doesn't show me the data from database.

Comment: this is the error that i get.

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'Tile.price' in 'field list'") [SQL: 'SELECT `Tiles`.id AS `Tiles_id`, `Tiles`.name AS `Tiles_name`, `Tiles`.size AS `Tiles_size`, `Tiles`.description AS `Tiles_description`, `Tiles`.price AS `Tiles_price`,